# Too much space at the top of image in TLF using Flex3

Tags: apache-flex, image, tlf

When insert an image into TLF in flex3, I found that image in TLF is displayed in a square area. so there is some space at the top of the image. See the attached image for this problem.

[image: too much space at the top of image in TLF in Flex3]

How to remove this space? I try the following method, But it doesn't work!

```
var graphic_element:InlineGraphicElement = IEditManager(activeFlow.interactionManager).insertInlineGraphic(foreignElementUrl, width, height, "none");

graphic_element.paddingTop = 0;
graphic_element.paddingBottom = 0;
graphic_element.paddingRight = 0;
graphic_element.paddingLeft = 0; 
IEditManager(activeFlow.interactionManager).applyParagraphFormat(graphic_element);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
inlineGraphicElement.textDecoration = null;
inlineGraphicElement.alignmentBaseline = TextBaseline.ASCENT;
inlineGraphicElement.lineHeight = "100%";
```

Comment: Thanks, The last statement is the key.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is useful if you create your textFlow from an HTML source. It will correct for every images in the textflow the display.

```
static private function _InlineGraphicElementCorrection(children:Array):void
{
    var numChildren:int = children.length;
    for (var i:int=0; i<numChildren; i++)
    {
        if( children[i].hasOwnProperty('mxmlChildren') )
            _InlineGraphicElementCorrection(children[i].mxmlChildren);
        if( !(children[i] is InlineGraphicElement) )
            continue;

        var graphicElement : InlineGraphicElement = children[i];
        graphicElement.textDecoration = null;
        graphicElement.alignmentBaseline = TextBaseline.ASCENT;
        graphicElement.lineHeight = "100%";
    }
}

static public function importHtmlToFlow(html:String):TextFlow
{
    var flow : TextFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(html.replace(/[\r\n]/ig, ""), TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
    _InlineGraphicElementCorrection(flow.mxmlChildren);
    return flow
}
```